# Programatically set the keyboard caps lock button to ON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, capslock

When a user of mine types text into a `UITextView`, I would like the `caps lock` modifier to be set to `true` so that if they subsequently press the caps lock button it will switch to lower-case text.

What I would like to see is the keyboard's caps button in blue when the `UITextView` becomes the first responder. I can't find the right setting in the docs or SO.

Comment: When a question is asked 2 YEARS AFTER the "duplicate", especially when iOS changes so rapidly, it should NOT be considered a duplicate. When are we going to get version tags?

Answer (score -2):

try this one

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [[text1.text stringByAppendingString:string] uppercaseString];
    text1.text = newString;
    return NO;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this will capitalize the text, not set the caps lock on the keyboard.